# Qt frozen Column ( Text stretch on two tables)

Tags: qt, text, stretch

I have 2 tables, one on top of another to achieve frozen Column (left side), but in some row, I would like to have some Text stretch across entire row.

How can I make it to display as a line without any missing characters in between ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Allow word wrap in table cells. 
2) Show full cell text as tooltip.

Comment: Thanks.... does it means that, it is not possible to show in a line stretch up to 2  tables?